# "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" while copying file to Hadoop HDFS from Java code

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, virtualbox

I am trying out some simple Java code to copy file from my local system to HDFS. This is how my simple method looks like:

```
private static void copyFileToHDFS() throws IOException
{
    config.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000");
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
    Path localfsSourceDir = new Path("D:\\file1");
    Path hdfsTargetDir = new Path ("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/dir/");
    hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(localfsSourceDir, hdfsTargetDir);      //throws Exception
}
```

This is giving me following Exception on last line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine; Host Details : local host is: "01hw713648/10.163.5.139"; destination host is: "127.0.0.1":9000; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at $Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at $Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1965)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1898)
    at HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.copyFileToHDFS(HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.java:64)
    at HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.main(HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:520)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:979)
```

**My Setup**

I am running Hadoop cluster in Ubuntu VM running on VirtualBox (which is in turn running on Windows). I have cluster up running perfectly. I am running this java code on Windows. I have set up port forwarding rules on Virtual Box as follows:

```
   Name                    Protocol      Host-ip          Host-port       Guest-Ip       Guest-port
   datanode                tcp           <left empty>     50075           <guest-ip>     50075 
   dfs web ui              tcp           <left empty>     50070           <guest-ip>     50070
   mapred apps             tcp           <left empty>     8088            <guest-ip>     8088
   hbase web ui            tcp           <left empty>     16010           <guest-ip>     16010
   hdfs                    tcp           <left empty>     9000            <guest-ip>     9000 
   regionserver web ui     tcp           <left empty>     16301           <guest-ip>     16301
   ssh                     tcp           <left empty>     22              <guest-ip>     22
```

which allows me to connect to various services on VM:

- I am able to connect to VM using putty
- Also able to open various hadoop web uis in browser inside Windows: Namenode web ui, HMaster webui, Regionserver webui

**Update**

Some online solutions for similar error but not in Hadoop context suggested to restart eclipse. So I just tried that. Now getting slightly different error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host; Host Details : local host is: "01hw713648/10.163.5.139"; destination host is: "127.0.0.1":9000;
```

with exactly same stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved. I specified `localhost` in all hadoop xyz-site.xml files. I changed them all to contain `<guest-vm-ip>`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got exactly this error when the port specified was wrong. I had specified 50070 instead of 9000.

I used a host-only adapter, hence no port-forwarding was required. I connected to 192.168.x.x in the Linux VM from the windows host. I also made sure the name node was listening on 0.0.0.0:9000 in the core-site.xml. Firewall and SE linux were disabled in the VM. I have the setup now working.